# What does this "-" in jinja2 template engine do?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, templates, jinja2

I am learning jinja2 because Google App Engine recommends it.

I found this example on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinja_%28template_engine%29

```
  {%- for item in item_list %}
    {{ item }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
  {%- endfor %}
```

What is the "-" in "{%- for"?

Also, where can I find jinja2 examples (better with Google App Engine)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Regarding examples,  this link shows you how to set up templates https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates. The documentation on jinja site will also have examples.

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401106/dashes-in-jinja-templates

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dashes in jinja templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401106/dashes-in-jinja-templates)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It suppresses extra vertical spacing, commonly used when you don't want excessive spacing between elements you're looping through.

> If you put an minus sign (-) to the start or end of a block (for
>   example a for tag), a comment or variable expression you can remove
>   the whitespaces after or before that block

See: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#whitespace-control

Answer (score 8):

As you implied the Google App Engine and Django use Jinja.
Jinja uses the dash to remove or add whitespace within a block.
`{%-` by itself means current line should have no empty lines between current and previous  line
`-%}` by itself means current line should have a single empty line above it
`{%-` and `-%}` means current line should be flush with previous line

In your example, you have dashes for the `for` loop. This will leave no space between the items. If you did not have this dash, it will leave a blank space between each item.

You can experiment here:
http://jinja.quantprogramming.com

Additional links:
[Documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#whitespace-control)
[Credit](https://picostitch.com/blog/2017/01/21-the-magic-dash-in-jinja-template-block/#:%7E:text=What%20the%20heck%20does%20-%25%7D,removes%20whitespaces%20inside%20a%20block.)