# What dashes mean in jinja templates?

Tags: jinja2

Found some of these in jinja files:

```
</extension>
{%- else -%}
<extension name="blabla">
```

And also

```
{% if freeswitch_dispatcher -%}
<extension name="hold_unhold">
```

See the dashes ?  Any idea what it's for ?

Comment: far easier to find this on SO than in the official doco :)

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813422/what-does-this-in-jinja2-template-engine-do

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Turns out that `+` and `-` are there for [whitespace control](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#whitespace-control) purpose.

> You can manually disable the lstrip_blocks behavior by putting a plus sign (+) at the start of a block
>   [...]
>   You can also strip whitespace in templates by hand. If you put an minus sign (-) to the start or end of an block (for example a for tag), a comment or variable expression you can remove the whitespaces after or before that block

Answer (score 22):

It's for controlling whitespace within a block.
`{%-` by itself means current line should have no empty lines between current and previous  line
`-%}` by itself means current line should have a single empty line above it
`{%-` and `-%}` means current line should be flush with previous line

You can experiment here:
http://jinja.quantprogramming.com

Additional links:
[Documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#whitespace-control)
[Credit](https://picostitch.com/blog/2017/01/21-the-magic-dash-in-jinja-template-block/#:%7E:text=What%20the%20heck%20does%20-%25%7D,removes%20whitespaces%20inside%20a%20block.)