# dash(-) character in jinja2 for loop and macro fomat

Tags: jinja2

I read document says the format for jinja2 for loop and macro are as below

```
{% for my_item in my_collection %}
{% endfor %}

{% macro macro_name(arg1, arg2) %} 
{% endmacro %}
```

But when I read someone's code, there always have a dash(-) next to the %.
like

```
{% for my_item in my_collection -%}
{% endfor -%}

{%- macro macro_name(arg1, arg2) -%} 
{%- endmacro -%}
```

Is there a reason for the dash or it is purely cosmatic and can be ignored?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove unnecessary whitespace from Jinja rendered template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775207/remove-unnecessary-whitespace-from-jinja-rendered-template)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dashes in jinja templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401106/dashes-in-jinja-templates)